# Problems of shifting columns when reading CSV-file in R

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I am trying to read in a large csv file using the data.table::fread module.

```
data.table::fread("/data.csv")
```

However, this return the following error:

> Stopped early on line 490763. Expected 21 fields but found 11.

After doing some research, I see that this specific error also rises in Sublime, where one row is split into two rows. I suspect that there might be a newline character in a string (\n). So for instance, the string could look like this:

`"This may rise a problem \n and splits the string to a new line"`   will result in:

```
"This may rise a problem
and splits the string to a new line"
```

For instance, using the readLines module in R, I also see that within the string, a new line is created. Obviously, this messes up the order of my rows/column and rows are not read in correctly. The same problem also rises in Excel for the same dataset.

I tried to fix this with a SED-command within my fread-statement, for instance to replace the \n between quotes to something else (e.g. a space). Unfortunately, I was not able to solve this problem due to lack of knowledge using SED-commands within fread statements.

Do you have any ideas how I could fix this problem and read in all rows correctly? I am open to use any other R package to read in CSVs. However, I try to build a solution which will work in an R-script, so not first by using terminal commands. Thank you in advance. I am working on a Mac.

Comment: Please provide multiple example rows from your file, including problem row.

Comment: One possible solution can be to read the entre csv in a single column with sep = "|"(or any other symbol not in data). And then delete the row which is causing the problem & then save it again. 
Another approach can be by using the __skip__ parameter. Read data till 490762 rows in 1 data frame & rows after 490763 into another data frame.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to look into the discussion on a similar issue with `fread`on Github:
https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1812

I would try the `fill = TRUE`option first of all. If this doesn't help the last answer in the discussion above might guide you to a solution.

Comment: It is indeed a relevant discussion and closely related to my specific issue. I tried to play around with the options and cmd within the `fread` module, without success so far.